# (push x nil) VS (push x place-that-stores-the-empty-list)

Tags: common-lisp

Why is it not possible to `push` directly on a list like `'(1 2 3)` or `NIL`?

Specifically:
Why is possible to do

```
> (let ((some-list nil))
    (push 42 some-list))

(42)
```

but not to do something like

```
(push 42 nil)
```

or

```
(push 42 '(1 2 3))
```

What is the **reasoning behind this implementation**?

Comment: `PUSH` is a place modifying macro. It `CONS`es a value to whatever is stored in the place (a variable is one kind of a place), and stores the result there. If you don't want to modify a place, you can just call `CONS` directly.

Comment: What would you expect `(push 42 '(1 2 3))` to do?

Comment: @Rainer: I expected that `push` checks first if the second arg is `nil` or a list and if so returns `(cons x nil)` or `(cons x '(1 2 3))`. But as jkiiski pointed out, i completely missed the obvious: `cons` odes that just fine.

Comment: Right. PUSH is supposed to have side-effect. Since it should work with variables, it needs to be a macro to do so.

Answer (score 4):

With macro `push` the second argument needs to be a place to be modified. Here are some examples:

Lets make two variables:

```
(defparameter *v* (list 2 4))
(defparameter *v-copy* *v*)
```

Then we push `0`

```
(push 1 *v*) ; ==> (1 2 4)
*v-copy*     ; ==> (2 4) (unaltered)

; the reason is that the variable is changed, not its value
(macroexpand '(push 1 v))
; ==> (setq v (cons 1 v))
```

`push` can use other things as second argument. Lets try a `cons`

```
(push 3 (cdr *v-copy*))
*v-copy*  ; ==> (2 3 4)
; since the tail of *v* is the *v-copy* *v* is changed too
*v*       ; ==> (1 2 3 4)

(macroexpand-1 '(push 2 (cdr *v-copy*)))
; ==> (rplacd v (cons 2 (cdr *v-copy*)))
```

If your examples were valid, what should it really have done? Lets do the nil first:

```
(macroexpand '(push 42 nil))
; ==> (setq nil (cons 42 nil))
```

This treats `nil` just as any other variable and if this worked `nil` would never be the empty list again. It would have been a list with one element, `42` and a different value than `()`. In Common Lisp `nil` is a constant and cannot be mutated. I've created a lisp once where `nil` was a variable like any other and a small typo redefined `nil` making the programs behave strange with no apparent reason.

Lets try your literal quoted list.

```
(macroexpand '(push 42 (quote (1 2 3))))
; ==> (let ((tmp (1 2 3)))
;      (funcall #'(setf quote) (cons 42 'tmp) tmp))
```

It doesn't seem the `push` macro differentiates between special form `quote` and those types that has set their `setf` function. It won't work and it doesn't make sense. Anyway in the same manner as mutating the binding `nil` if this  changed the literal data `'(1 2 3)` to `'(43 1 2 3)` would you then expect to get `(43 1 2 3)` every time you evaluated `(1 2 3)` from there on? I imagine that would be the only true effect of mutating a constant. If this was allowed you should be allowed to redefine `4` to be `5` so that evaluating `4` or `(+ 2 2)` shows the result `5`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know that nil is a literal / constant in CL. I expected that `push` checks if the second arg is `nil` and if so returns like `(cons x nil)`

Comment: @Frank `push` is never used for it's returned value but the side effect it does by mutating a place. In the event for `(let ((v nil)) (push 1 v))` the reason to use `push` is gone since you don't use `v` and it goes out of scope. You might as well have written `(cons 1 nil)`.